# Send post changes to set email addresses (not users or subscribers)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, posts, functions, email

## What I have

I am using the "[The Events Calendar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/)" plugin on my site to coordinate a team of employees. I want to be able to send an automated email containing the body of an event post (post-type is not `$post`, but `$tribe_events` instead) each time it's updated, but only to the employees concerned by that post.

To get the email addresses, I have set up a meta box in the `$tribe_events` post-type editor as a plugin based off something I found online for adding social media buttons and it works fine:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_box' );

function add_custom_box( $tribe_events ) {
    add_meta_box(
        'animateurs', // ID, should be a string.
        'Animateurs', // Meta Box Title.
        'social_services', // Your call back function, this is where your form field will go.
        'tribe_events', // The post type you want this to show up on, can be post, page, or custom post type.
        'side', // The placement of your meta box, can be normal or side.
        'core' // The priority in which this will be displayed.
    );
}

function social_services( $tribe_events )
{
// Get post meta value using the key from our save function in the second paramater.
$custom = get_post_meta($tribe_events->ID, '_social_services', true);

?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="anim_patrick" name="social_services[]" value="patrick@example.com" <?php echo (in_array('patrick@example.com', $custom)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>>
    <label for="anim_patrick"></label>Patrick<br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="anim_jeff" name="social_services[]" value="jeff@example.com" <?php echo (in_array('jeff@example.com', $custom)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>>
    <label for="anim_jeff"></label>Jeff<br>
<?php
}     

function save_extra_fields(){
global $post;

if(isset( $_POST['social_services'] ))
{
    $custom = $_POST['social_services'];
    $old_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_social_services', true);
    // Update post meta
    if(!empty($old_meta)){
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_social_services', $custom);
    } else {
        add_post_meta($post->ID, '_social_services', $custom, true);
    }
  }
// update_post_meta($post->ID, "producers", $_POST["producers"]);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_extra_fields' );
```

**The result**

[image: What the above code adds to the editor]

This successfully saves the email addresses of the employees concerned by the event post.

I can use this code to show the array of those email addresses (on a page - not what I want to do. This is purely to show how to get the email addresses from the array):

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_social_services', true); $anims = implode (", ", $meta); echo $anims; ?>
```

## What I need

Now I'm just stuck on the last part, which is to send an email containing the new updated post content to the email addresses contained in `$anims` every time a `$tribe_events` post-type is updated.

How can I achieve that?

PS: I'm a nube at PHP. This is my first attempt at something like this.

Comment: If you found the solution then mark your own answer as accepted to signal the question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to use [wp_mail](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) to send emails containing in your array.

Here is how you can achieve that using [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action hook.

```
/**
 * To send email on updating your event post
 *
 * @param int $post_id The post ID.
 * @param post $post The post object.
 * @param bool $update Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
 */
function send_email_on_event_update( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    $post_type = 'tribe_events';  // your post type

    // If this isn't a 'tribe_events' post, No need to send emails
    if ( $post_type != $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    // - Now to Send emails

    // first get array of your emails
    $all_emails = get_post_meta($post_id , '_social_services', true); // this is suppose to be variable containing array of emails


    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $subject = $post_title;

    $message = "This event has been updated:\n\n";
    $message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url;
    $message .= "keep adding what ever you want to send in this email...";


    // Send email to $all_emails.
    wp_mail( $all_emails, $subject, $message );

}
// have kept the priority to 11 to make sure we get the content for email after every thing is saved
add_action( 'save_post', 'send_email_on_event_update', 11, 3 );
```

Haven't test this code yet. But I'm sure this would work for you.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Are you sure $all_emails is an array of email ids?

Comment: When I try putting `<?php $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_social_services', true); $anims = implode (", ", $meta); echo $anims; ?>` into a template (like `footer.php`) it shows the email addresses that correspond to the boxes I have ticked for that post in this format : `patrick@example.com, jeff@example.com`

Comment: OK just updated code. Actually your `$meta` is the array containing all email ids which you are converting into string using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working. Is there anything I should check that might be affecting it? I've put your code just after mine in the same plugin.

Comment: Are you working on live server? Because if you are testing on local then email thing is not going to work.

Comment: Yes I'm working on the live site hosted on Bluehost.

Comment: Try sending email to just single email just to make sure every thing else is fine. Just declare `$all_emails = 'your_email@example.com'` and then upadate your event to test the functionality.

Comment: Ok I've just tried it and it doesn't send me the email.

Comment: Could the problem come from the checkboxes in the meta box? `<?php echo (in_array('patrick@example.com', $custom)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>`

Comment: OK have tested on local server. Change the priority of action hook to 11.

Comment: Yes! That seems to be it! It's working perfectly! Thank you so much

Comment: Just note : You'll need to add `."\n";`onto the end of the line which says `$message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url ."\n";`, otherwise "keep" gets added onto the end of the post URL.

Comment: Glad to know that!